# The painting is not representative of his work of the period

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The painting is not representative of his work of the period.

Q. work of the period

work about the period? or the period's work?

Comment: A. His work at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often talk about artists' work being classified into periods of time which can be distinguished: for example, Picasso's "blue period", where his work mostly contained shades of blue.

In this case the writer is saying that a particular painting is not very similar to that artist's other works from around the same time.